# SQL - Removing Duplicate without 'hard' coding?

Tags: sql, duplicates, where-clause, procedure, clause

Heres my scenario.

I have a table with 3 rows I want to return within a stored procedure, rows are email, name and id. id must = 3 or 4 and email must only be per user as some have multiple entries.

I have a Select statement as follows

```
SELECT
     DISTINCT email,
     name,
     id
from table
where
     id = 3
     or id = 4
```

Ok fairly simple but there are some users whose have entries that are both 3 and 4 so they appear twice, if they appear twice I want only those with ids of 4 remaining. I'll give another example below as its hard to explain.

Table -

```
Email              Name    Id
jimmy@domain.com   jimmy   4
brian@domain.com   brian   4
kevin@domain.com   kevin   3
jimmy@domain.com   jimmy   3
```

So in the above scenario I would want to ignore the jimmy with the id of 3, any way of doing this without hard coding?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Oracle etc...)? Please _always_ tag SQL questions with the tag as there may be some additional feature of the RDBMS that you are using that can help.

Comment: Sorry its SQL Server so T-SQL. Thanks for all the responses. Think the Max(id) should do the trick, much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
     email,
     name,
     max(id)
from table
where
     id in( 3, 4 )
group by email, name
```

Comment: You must mean MAX() from the OPs example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
SELECT Email, Name, MAX(Id) FROM Table WHERE Id IN (3, 4) GROUP BY Email;
```

Comment: Unless it's MySQL you *must* GROUP BY Name as well.

Comment: T-SQL has to have  GROUP BY Name too.  This also doesn't account for the same name having different email addresses, which is a possibility, given the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using `Having Count(*) > 1` may be useful to find duplicated records.

```
select * from table group by Email having count(*) > 1
```

or

```
select * from table group by Email having count(*) > 1 and id > 3.
```

The solution provided before with the select `MAX(ID)` from table sounds good for this case.
This maybe an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

What RDMS are you using?  **This will return only one "Jimmy"**, using `RANK()`:

```
SELECT A.email, A.name,A.id
FROM SO_Table A
INNER JOIN(
SELECT 
email, name,id,RANK() OVER (Partition BY name ORDER BY ID DESC) AS COUNTER
FROM SO_Table B  
) X ON X.ID = A.ID AND X.NAME = A.NAME
WHERE X.COUNTER = 1
```

Returns:

```
 email          name    id
 ------------------------------
 jimmy@domain.com   jimmy   4
 brian@domain.com   brian   4
 kevin@domain.com   kevin   3
```